# Converting columns into Rows from 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a query which joins 2 tables and the query I have from 2 tables is:

```
SELECT A.ID,A.CSTID,B.OCT,B.NOV,B.DEC
FROM TBL A 
INNER JOIN TBL B ON A.ID = B.NUM
```

Output of above query is:

```
ID   CSTID  OCT  NOV  DEC
--------------------------
1    1A     20   25   30
```

I want the output as:

```
ID   CSTID  MONTHS  VALUE
-------------------------
1    1A     OCT     20
1    1A     NOV     25
1    1A     DEC     30
```

I used the below query but I am getting an error:

```
SELECT 
    A.ID, A.CSTID,
    C.MONTHS,
    C.VALUE
FROM 
    TBL A 
INNER JOIN 
    TBL B ON A.ID = B.NUM
UNPIVOT 
    (VALUE FOR MONTHS IN (OCT, NOV, DEC)) C
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @Matt The column 'Id' was specified multiple times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the joined result around with `select * from ...` and use the `unpivot`.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT A.ID,A.CSTID,B.OCT as october,B.NOV as november, B.DEC
as december 
 FROM TBL A 
INNER JOIN TBL B ON A.ID = B.NUM ) T
UNPIVOT (
         VALUE FOR MONTHS IN (october,november,december)
        ) C
```

Comment: moving my answer here vkp beat me by 30 seconds, nice one!  But do note that you should first create the joined result either as a CTE or a nested select and then next UNPIVOT it.  In the end only the UNPIVOT table alias is available for you to select in your column list (e.g. c)

Comment: @vkp Thanks. It worked. How to do full name for months for ex: oct like October and Nov like November

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNPIVOT`:

```
SELECT ID,
       CSTID,
       MonthName AS MONTHS,
       Month AS VALUE
FROM
(
    SELECT A.ID,
           A.CSTID,
           B.OCT AS OCTOBER,
           B.NOV AS NOVEMBER,
           B.DEC AS DECEMBER
    FROM TBL A 
    INNER JOIN TBL B
        ON A.ID = B.NUM
) t1
UNPIVOT
(
    Month FOR MonthName IN (OCTOBER, NOVEMBER, DECEMBER)
) AS t2
```

**Comment:**

The only issue I see with your original query is that you don't wrap the join in parenthesis and give it an alias.  If my solution works for you then you will know this to be the case.

Comment: I knew you would get there but vkp already answered it, I removed my correct answer too because his was correct and he beat me by 28 seconds.  Note you can just say Value FOR Months IN (Oct..... instead of having to re-alias the columns

Comment: Who says @vkp got it right?  He is selecting all columns which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: all of the columns are the only ones that exist after then unpivot.  * and your column list will be equivalent

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i tried the same but i am getting the error as Invalid Column Name 'OCT'

Comment: @peter Alias the column names as `OCTOBER` in the query, and then use them in the `UNPIVOT`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this:

```
SELECT * INTO TBL FROM (
VALUES(1, '1A',1,20,25,30)) as x(ID, CSTID, Num, OCT,  NOV,  DEC)

SELECT A.ID, A.CSTID, tt.Month_Name, tt.Month_Value
FROM TBL as A
INNER JOIN TBL as B
ON A.ID = B.NUM
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
    (B.OCT, 'OCT'), (B.NOV, 'NOV'), (B.DEC, 'DEC')
) tt (Month_Value, Month_Name)
```